# What should I use as a stable and safe unique object identifier for serialization purposes?

Tags: c#, object, serialization

In my game, I have a bunch of objects of the type 'Area' which are always different from each other. They store data such as the spawn points for characters, resources that can be found, the name, etc.

Sometimes I wan't to store the area that the player is currently up to. I don't need to store the whole area, just some kind of key that indicates what area.

At the moment I'm using an enum, however it's annoying to have to add a new enum for every area. I was wondering, is there some more safe, self-managing way of tackling this problem? I could use the name string, however if I ever decide I want to change the name of an area during release, it has the potential to ruin peoples save data.

Is there a technique to this of some sort?

Comment: [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.7.2)s were designed for this.

Comment: @DourHighArch Hi Dour, cheers for the reply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't I still have to assign the GUID for every object every time I decide to add a new one?

Comment: Yes; if that is a problem you need to update your question to explain why.

Comment: @DourHighArch It's okay, it's not a problem, I just thought maybe there was some way for objects to create it for themselves, but it makes sense to me why this isn't possible.

Comment: Your class could in fact create it for itself.  If you already have one, pass it in the ctor or just replace it.